# How can a glfwSleep() cause a segfault?

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, sleep, glfw

in my multithraded application, I'm using a sleep() function (the one from the GLFW library):

```
glfwSleep(..);
```

and it apparently leads my application to segfaulting as my call stack shows:

```
#0 76CFC2BC WaitForSingleObjectEx() (C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll:??)
#1 00000016 ??() (??:??)
#2 0000006C ??() (??:??)
#3 00000000 ??() (??:??)
```

The `glfwSleep()` is used inside a thread.  Is that dangerous? Why is my program segfaulting as a consequence to that?

#### Edit:

When the parameter of the `glfwSleep()` is < 0.02 (secs) it doesn't segfault!

#### Edit 2:

From the official documentation of GLFW :

> Writing threaded applications may be
> very awkward before you get used to
> it, but there are a few key rules that
> are fairly simple to follow:
>
> - ALWAYS assure exclusive access to data that is shared between threads!
> - Make sure that threads are synchronized properly!
> - **NEVER busy wait!**

I think i got my answer..have to find an alternative now..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the GLFW wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GLFW):

> GLFW doesn't work well with GHC
>   threads, forkIO or threadDelay. So
>   avoid them if you can.

Comment: hmm thanks ! I tried to simulate a delay by creating a function that displays 10000 integers but i got a segfault here too :(

Comment: Amokrane: Segfaults are usually the result of doing something inappropriate with pointers.  See how much you can shrink your program down while still getting the segfault.  And you can always post another question if you have a trivially sized program that's still causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

Is segfault'ed thread same thread of caller of the glfwSleep()?

it seems that the crash caused by the call of WaitForMultipleObjectsEx API.
does you specifies and pass to the correct sync objects and numbers to WaitForMultipleObjectsEx?

Comment: 1/ Yes.
2/ Didn't understand the question ? I'm just doing a: glfwSleep(0.5); notice that under 0.02 it doesn't segfault !

Comment: i checked the source tree of GLFW.
in windows, glfwSleep never calls WaitForMultipleObjectsEx but Sleep.
(see: http://glfw.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/glfw/trunk/lib/win32/win32_time.c?view=markup)

check your source code using WaitForMultipleObjectsEx API.

Answer (score 1):

To quote [*The Pragmatic Programmer*](http://www.pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer),

> **``select’’ Isn’t Broken**
>
> It is rare to
>   find a bug in the OS or the compiler,
>   or even a third-party product or
>   library. The bug is most likely in the
>   application.

Why is your program calling `WaitForSingleObjectEx()` when `glfwSleep()` calls `Sleep()`? Well, even though you don't have the source code to `Sleep()`, it's not completely a black box. Disassemble `Sleep()` and you'll probably see (depending on which version of Windows you have) that `Sleep()` either calls or tail-calls `SleepEx()`. On XP, `SleepEx()` calls `NtDelayExecutionThread()`, and on Vista it calls `WaitForSingleObjectEx()`.

So what happened to the rest of your stack? 00000016, 0000006C, and 00000000 aren't valid return addresses. I would not be surprised if somewhere in your code, you pass a pointer to a stack-allocated buffer to another thread, and while your program is sleeping, that other thread corrupts the first thread's stack. Step into `Sleep()`, put a memory breakpoint on the return address, and you may be able to catch the culprit.